# how to choose $a$ and $f$ in the summation by parts formula

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, analytic-number-theory

A common version of summation by part formula is
$$
\sum_{n\le x}a(n)f(n)=A(x)f(x)-\int_1^xA(t)f'(t)\,dt
$$
where $A(x)=\sum_{n\le x}a(n)$.

To get a formula for $\sum_{n\le x} b(n)$, we often need to write $b(n)=a(n)f(n)$ for some $a$ and $f$. The choice of $a$ and $f$ may not be unqiue. My question is: is there a general principle to select $a$ and $f$? For example, when $b(n)=\frac{\log n}{n}$, shall we set $a(n)=\log n$ and $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ or the other way around $a(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ and $f(n)=\log n$?
I did the calculation in this case and it seems to me that both choices gave the same main term and error term. I guess in some other examples, one choice of $a$ and $f$ will lead better error term than the other choices.

Comment: Of course the general principle is to choose $a,f$ such that we know $\sum_{n \le x} a(n)$ quite well and $\int_1^x f'(t)A(t)dt$ can be estimated. In the context of the prime number theorem, the choices are obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Euler's summation formula, or more generally Abel's summation formula is often applied in analytic number theory. Then number-theoretical considerations immediately suggest how to choose $a(n)$ and $f(t)$. A nice example is the proof of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions. It uses Abel's formula (and something more) to obtain
$$
\sum_{p\le x,p\equiv h(k)}\frac{\log(p)}{p}=\frac{1}{\phi(k)}\log(x)+O(1),
$$
see Tom Apostol's book on Analytic Number Theory.

Comment: The sum I'm interested in is not over an arithmetic progressions.

Comment: You also can have a sum your are interested, of course, but you did not say in the question, which ones are allowed resp. forbidden. Sums of the type $ \sum_{n\le x}a(n)f(n)$ play a very important role in number theory, and then the context very much suggests how to chose $a$ and $f$.